# Gradle dependency json-simple error

Tags: gradle, junit, dependencies, build.gradle, json-simple

I'm fairly new to Gradle so I'm trying to build a Java project and not sure about the dependencies.  I have never gotten Gradle configured to be able to do my tests or now a jar file to compile and run.

My `build.gradle`:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
   jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    compile 'org.json:json:20160212'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And this is what I get on the console stating that it doesn't see my import:

```
 error: package org.json.simple does not exist
 import org.json.simple.JSONParser;
```

Here's my class:

```java
import org.json.simple.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class FileLoader {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    int count = 0;

    try {
      Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
          "Consumers.json"));

      JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
      JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("people");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Gradle, and what does your class look like? Could you add the minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you download the [JSON jar](https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/json/json/20160212/json-20160212.jar) specified, and list its contents (e.g. with `jar tf`), it does not contain the `org.json.simple` package.

So the problem is simply that you need another jar.

EDIT:

I don't know if this is the intent, but an educated guess: if you add this dependency to `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
```

and these imports:

```
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
// import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.*;
```

then the example compiles (for me).

Answer (score 9):

Adding this to my build.gradle file works:

```
implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have the correct dependency to use `org.json.simple` libraries.

I think you may want the coordinates for a dependency like https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple , but it is not easy to find the Maven coordinates.

If you wanted to use that library you could add these parts to your build script:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
}
```

Add this to the file to fix imports:

```
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
```

Then, you just have to fix the usage errors in your class definition.

Also, that library looks unmaintained so you may want to explore other JSON parsing libraries.